# How to setup wildcard for custom domain in amazon route53

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-s3

I linked a domain using Amazon route53 with an s3 bucket and it's working good. I tried to add a wildcard entry for sub domain but it keeps on showing bucket not found.

What I try to do is any sub domain I open for my domain the default file for it become main domain index file.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Route 53 is not wildcard record friendly. You can simply create an alias record for your subdomain to point to the your S3 bucket.

Consider this is your Route 53 subdomain:

[image: Route 53 Alias]

You can read more about Route 53 aliases here:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/CreatingAliasRRSets.html